# Gatsby - "value" must contain at least one of [icon, icons]

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, gatsby, package.json

When I run gatsby develop in console this error shows up:

> ```
> ERROR #11331  PLUGIN
> Invalid plugin options for "gatsby-plugin-manifest":
> - "value" must contain at least one of [icon, icons]
> ```

I just cloned a starter github branch [here](https://github.com/wrongakram/ar-episode2/tree/starter) and install all node modules. Keep in mind, that I am new to react/gatsby.
I searched on the web for this error but did not find any helpful info.

This is my gatsby-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-feed`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `Gatsby Starter Blog`,
        short_name: `GatsbyJS`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#ffffff`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `${__dirname}/src/assets`,
      },
    },  
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `assets`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/assets`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

This is my package.json :

```json
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-default",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simple starter to get up and developing quickly with Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Kyle Mathews <mathews.kyle@gmail.com>",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.7",
    "framer-motion": "^1.10.2",
    "gatsby": "^2.19.45",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.2.44",
    "gatsby-plugin-feed": "^2.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.10.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.0.41",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.1.24",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.4.13",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^3.2.1",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.1.56",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.3.19",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-canvas": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^8.26.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "styled-normalize": "^8.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^1.19.1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

Any help would be appriciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two instances of the `gatsby-plufin manifest` in your `gatsby-config.js`. Delete one of them:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-feed`,  
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `assets`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/assets`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

If you don't want to use an icon, since it's not a mandatory property you can delete it. However, if you are using it, you must provide a valid icon, not a folder:

```
icon: `${__dirname}/src/assets/iconName.png`,
```

Comment: ```icon: `${__dirname}/src/assets`,``` it's not a mandatory property. You can remove it if you don't have any, but you can't provide a folder instead of a valid icon. Choose one of two instances but if you add a `icon`, provide it, if not, remove it.

Comment: This property is already deleted in my `gatsby-config.js` file and it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: Just added `icon: 'src/assets/img/website-icon.png',` back into `gatsby-config.js`. Works. Don't want it right now though. Seems mandatory on my end. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

```
  icon: `${__dirname}/src/assets`,
```

The above line must be pointed to a file, not a folder

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-manifest/#hybrid-mode-configuration

```
 module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `GatsbyJS`,
        short_name: `GatsbyJS`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#f7f0eb`,
        theme_color: `#a2466c`,
        display: `standalone`,
 icon: `src/images/icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      icons: [
        {
          src: `/favicons/android-chrome-192x192.png`,
          sizes: `192x192`,
          type: `image/png`,
        },
        {
          src: `/favicons/android-chrome-512x512.png`,
          sizes: `512x512`,
          type: `image/png`,
        },
      ], // Add or remove icon sizes as desired
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I found this code but did not know where to put it.